# subscribe to windows system events native c++

Tags: c++, windows, winlogon

I want  my c++ app to listen to windows system event like, logon, logoff, lock...
similar to: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/30389-To-detect-when-system-gets.aspx that is written in C#.
I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx#Y0m, but its a CLR code. Also, I see that SubscribeToSystemEvent function is in visual C++.

Does anyone know which methods to use in native c++?

please advise,

Liron

Answer (score 5):

Call [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28VS.85%29.aspx) to receive [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window messages when the session state changes. This includes logon, logoff, lock, unlock and others. Make sure you have a corresponding call to [WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before your program exits.

Alternatively, you could listen for [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window messages. The first allows you to prevent the user from logging off; the second tells you whether it's going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try krabset https://github.com/Microsoft/krabsetw which is wrapper. 
You can also check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2

Also look into New-WinEvent and Get-WinEvent by PowerShell